# Hibernate HQL instantiate object within object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

note: not using the real-life example, but typed the "mock" of my situation directly on stackoverflow, so please ignore syntax errors.

Say I have an 2 classes, where A is one-to-many of B. Ignore the lack of getters/setters

```
class A {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private List<B> kids;

    public A() {}
    public A(int a, int b) { this.a = a; this.b = b; }
}
class B {
    private int c;
    private int d;
    private A parent;

    public B() {}
    // what I'd like to use:
    public B(int c, int d, A a) { this.c = c; this.d = d; this.parent = a; }
    // current workaround:
    public B(int c, int d, int a, int b) {
        A pr = new A(); pr.setA(a); pr.setB(b);
        this.c = c; this.d = d; this.parent = pr;
    }
}
```

The goal is to create a String query which would query A and B and get an all-together object with only `query.list()` called (no after-setting)

Being how HQL is expressive, I know you can do stuff like:

```
select new A(a.column_1, a.column_2) from A a;
```

And with `HibernateTemplate` and `Query` using `query.list()` you get the instantiated A objects right away.

What my question here is whether I can instantiate within another instantiation? Something like

```
select new B(b.column_1, b.column_2, new A(a.column_1, a.column_2)) 
from A a, B b where a.a_id = b.a_id;
```

and actually use the constructor which I marked above as "prefered" constructor. 
When I tried using the method above, I got an exception:

```
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: A
```

Currently the only workaround I have is to use the other "workaround" constructor with a query like:

```
select new B(b.column_1, b.column_2, a.column_1, a.column_2) 
from A a, B b where a.a_id = b.a_id;
```

The main question would be, is what I want even possible? If yes, how? :)

Thanks, and if you have any questions regarding... my question, please shoot!

Thanks!

Comment: Why in hell do you call constructors of entties in your queries? Just use `select a from A a left join fetch a.kids`. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join

Comment: @JBNizet I know, right, purely idiotic. Unfortunately, legacy code is legacy code, and as I pointed out the above isn’t a real-life example. Let’s just say there are reasons as to why it’s being done this way (for the time being), and then when reasnoble times come, better refactorments will take place. Does that answer it?

Comment: No. An entity is an entity is an entity. Whether it's an old one or a new one, querying As and loading their kids can be done as in my comment.

Comment: @JBNizet Well, I like being wrong, means I learned something, when I think about it you might be completely right, it’d just require some refactoring due to you suggestion inverting my end objects from list of B to A. I’ll try to do something, not like I have a life or something. I’ll keep you posted about this working out in case you have life like I do and are interested

Comment: @JBNizet took a bit while, but you're right, the solution works very nicely and is performant. Great thanks, kind sir!

Comment: [Omar.Nassar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1450002) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67049239) saying "I think this is what you're looking for, check this out: [https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-37](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-37)"